# Unexpected results with delete method

Tags: python, tkinter

Found this exercise in a book to learn programming with Python 3... I have to create a new App class derived from Frame. It has to show a face and 2 buttons, one to draw an open mouth and the other one to draw a line instead (open and close the mouth - noob exercise).

Below is what I did and it almost work like it should : the button to open works fine and if there was a line (closed mouth), it deletes it, but the closed mouth button draws the line without deleting the open mouth, although it looks to me like I used exactly the same delete method to take care of that ...
My question : why is it working for one button and not the other one ? Do you get the same outcome ?

```
class Application(Frame):
    "main canvas and buttons"

    def __init__(self, boss =None):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.can = Canvas(self, width=400, height =400, bg ='ivory')
        self.can.pack(side =TOP, padx =5, pady =5)
        self.face=Visage(self.can, 50, 50)
        self.bouche=2
        Button(self, text ="Ouvrir", command =self.ouvrirBouche).pack(side =LEFT)
        Button(self, text ="Fermer", command =self.fermerBouche).pack(side =LEFT)

    def ouvrirBouche(self):
        "draws the open mouth and delete the closed one if any"
        if (self.bouche != 0):
            self.ouvre=cercle(self.can, 200, 260, 35)
            if (self.bouche ==1):
                print(self.bouche)
                self.can.delete(self.ferme)
            self.bouche=0

    def fermerBouche(self):
        "draws the closed mouth and delete the open one if any"
        if (self.bouche != 1):
            self.ferme= self.can.create_line(170, 260, 230, 260)
            if (self.bouche ==0):
                print(self.bouche)
                self.can.delete(self.ouvre)
            self.bouche=1


class Visage(object):
    "drawing a face in canvas canv"
    def __init__(self, canv, x, y):
        self.canv, self.x, self.y = canv, x, y
        cercle(canv, x+150, y+150, 130)
        cercle(canv, x+100, y+100, 20)
        cercle(canv, x+200, y+100, 20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=Tk()
    app=Application(root)
    app.pack(side=TOP)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably defined a function `cercle` that draws French circles.
The function should look like:

```
def cercle(canv, x, y, rad):
    return canv.create_oval(x-rad, y-rad, x+rad, y+rad, width=2)
```

Note that the function must ***return*** the circle object. Otherwise `self.ouvre` is None and then you can not delete it as you do not have a reference to the object in `self.can.delete(self.ouvre)`.

*Tested with python 3.2 in windows 7 64bit*